# PHPUnit configuration file and auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to use the phpunit configuration file to set a specific php-ini setting. When I try to set the **auto_prepend_file** to a file that exist, having tested both relative path and absolute path, it doesn't work.

I does however work if I set it in the php-ini file.
php.ini

```
[...]
auto_prepend_file=/path/to/project/config.php
[...]
```

What I'm trying to do is to load this config.php file before loading my testcase, because I have some functions and config variables I need access to. Maybe I can do it some other way than using auto_prepend_file!? Or do somebody know how to make it work this way!?

phpunit config file:

```
<phpunit>
  [...]
  <php>
    <ini name="auto_prepend_file" value="/path/to/project/config.php" />
  </php>
  [...]
</phpunit>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the `<ini>` tags to set values that can be set from within PHP using `ini_set()`.

So only ini values that are `PHP_INI_ALL`. The `auto_prepent_file` directive is `PHP_INI_PERDIR` ([**see the docs**](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php)) meaning it can't be set when php process is already running.

---

### For including a file before the tests are run you have two options:

Ether use the `--bootstrap file_to_run_before_tests_run.php` option

or use `php -d auto_prepend_file=yourfile.php /path/to/phpunit` to run phpunit.

Both ways will ensure the file contents are executed before any tests are executed with `--bootstrap` being the more common way to do that.

Comment: Ah that explains why I couldn't get to work! Thank you! 

Though, I was hoping that I wouldn't need to use anything like bootstrap.